# Remove file fails - Permission denied

Tags: php

i'm trying to remove a file using `unlink` but it return false.
At this point I can't get to the php.ini so as far as I know I can't see the error message. Or can I?

These are the lines I have for now:

```
echo chmod("MyFolder/testfile.jpg", 0777) ? "chmod Success " : "chmod Fail ";
echo unlink("MyFolder/testfile.jpg") ? "unlink Success" : "unlink Fail";
```

So the results for running this is `chmod Success unlink Fail`

```
echo is_readable("MyFolder/testfile.jpg") ? "Readable " : "Not readable ";
echo is_writable("MyFolder/testfile.jpg") ? "writable " : "Not writable ";
echo is_executable("MyFolder/testfile.jpg") ? "executable " : "Not executable ";
```

Running these lines I get `Readable Writable Not executeable`

I don't know what else to do

**Edit:**

Now when I can see errors and warnings I get this:

```
 Warning: unlink(MyFolder/testfile.jpg): Permission denied in xxx.php on line 19
```

**Edit2:**

Tried

```
$handle = fopen("MyFolder/testfile.jpg", "r");
fclose($handle);
unlink
```

but still `Permission denied`

Then I tried changing the working directory like this:

```
$old = getcwd();
chdir("MyFolder");
unlink("testfile.jpg");
chdir($old);
```

but same warning; `Permisson denied`

**Edit3:**

Tried `unlink(realpath("IPCAM/testfile.jpg"));`
same warning; `Permisson denied`

Comment: to see errors at the top of your php page add: `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); ini_set('html_errors', 0); error_reporting(-1);`

Comment: Thank you @rtfm, now I know that it's a permission problem

Comment: Try close file before delete: `fclose ("MyFolder/testfile.jpg");`

Comment: there are a few dozen dupes, basically, it will be the user PHP i running or the parent folder permissions

Comment: fclose takes a `resoure $handle`, I can't put the path as input parameter. And if I open the file and then close it using `fopen` and `fclose` I still get the same warning

Comment: Yes, I've found similiar questions, but the answers there didn't solve my problem

Comment: Legends tell us to try `unlink(realpath($filePath))` in these weird cases. You might want to try that.

Comment: be specific, what have you tried? what was the result?

Comment: @rtfm Updated the question

Comment: none of what you have tried actually changes any permissions - that's the issue

Comment: @rtfm How about giving me an example of what I can try then? I thought chmod would do it but clearly i'm wrong